# Uploading image using Spring, commons-file upload

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) and [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/) tutorial but without using maven.

Here is my config related to upload:

ApplicationContext.xml

```
..
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000">
</property></bean>
```

My form:

```
<form:form 
        action="${ contextPath }admin/add-product" 
        method="POST" modelAttribute="addInventoryItemDto"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
        ....
        <tr>
            <td><b>Image:</b></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
        </tr>
        ....
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/add-product", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String addProduct( 
    @ModelAttribute( "addInventoryItemDto" ) @Valid AddInventoryItemDto inventoryDto,
    @RequestParam( "image" ) MultipartFile img ) {
        System.out.println("ContentType:" + img.getContentType());
        return "admin/add-product";
    }
```

I'm getting `404 Bad Request` but when I remove the file related stuff in my `Controller` and `form` the request is properly sent to my controller

**What I'm I missing or did wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the `multipartResolver`

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000">
</property></bean>
```

to my `servlet-dispatcher` configuration. Seems like that multipartResolver is part of spring MVC not the spring core

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this tag:

```
  <spring:url value="/add-product?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" var="addItem"/>
```

And put this to the action attribute:

```
<form:form 
    action= "${addItem}" 
    method="POST" modelAttribute="addInventoryItemDto"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
    ....
    <tr>
        <td><b>Image:</b></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
    </tr>
    ....
```

If this isn’t working try also add the MultiPartHttpServletRequest object to your controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/add-product", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String addProduct( 
@ModelAttribute( "addInventoryItemDto" ) @Valid AddInventoryItemDto inventoryDto,
MultiPartHttpServletRequest request,
@RequestParam( "image" ) MultipartFile img ) {
    System.out.println("ContentType:" + img.getContentType());
    return "admin/add-product";
}
```